# D3 donut Slice goes blank on click

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

I have added an animation to a D3 dount chart. It is working fine in IE and Chrome but in Mozilla when I click on a slice it goes blank. I have used transition and ease for the animation.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivamgupta1411/c81t9kwp/)

```
d3.select(this)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease('elastic')
```

Comment: Strange which version of FF mine is v28 and i cannot recreate the issue.

Comment: @Cyril FF43 shows this error. Interestingly, some arcs work as expected while others don't. To make things worse, the behavior is not consistent, i.e. after a reload it may be a completely different set of arcs which erroneously disappear. Inspecting the elements via Firebug shows them still being part of the DOM, and you can have them appear again when forcing a rendering by using Firebug to manipulate some attributes of the element, its sibling text or its parent elements. Given all that, I'd consider it a FF bug.

Comment: thanks @altocumulus in that case, I think we should tag this with svg as it seems to be svg + FF issue.